# Can I force Ebean enhancement while sbt recompiles the project?

Tags: java, playframework, sbt, ebean

I have following hierarchy:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class BaseModel extends Model {
    // common persistent fields for all entities, (id, timestamps etc.)  
}

@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class SpecificModel extends BaseModel {
    // common persistent fields for only some entities  
}

@Entity
public class ExampleModel extends SpecificModel {

}
```

The BaseModel extends io.ebean.Model class.

### Problem:

When I make some code changes, the SBT will try to recompile only those classes that were affected by the change. This makes the compiler complaining that any class extending **SpecificModel** *is not abstract and does not override abstract method _ebean_intercept() in io.ebean.bean.EntityBean.*

I assume this happens when SBT recompiles only some sources, but those sources are not enhanced by the Ebean enhancer.

After running the **clean** command the compilation is successful, but it would be pain to clean and compile whole project again for every change.

**Is there a way to force the enhancement when recompiling? Or is the problem elsewhere? Or is it a bad practice to have two abstract MappedSuperclasses?**

Using: Play! 2.6.7, PlayEbean 4.0.6

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: @Saleh Not really, but in later versions of Play! it was happening only occasionally. So I just cleaned the project when it happened.